# Reacting to Operations on Secret Manager

Tags: gcloud, google-secret-manager

We want to use Secret Manager as a primary datastore for secrets.

When certain secrets change in the primary datastore, we want to react on that and update a secondary datastore (with the latest values).

Is there a way of reacting to when a Secret got created/changed/deleted without explicit polling?

Comment: In general, we don’t recommend duplicating secrets. This breaks auditability and having a single source of truth.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020-07-21, this is not currently possible, but notifications are on the roadmap.

Comment: I'll update this answer once we've solidified a plan, but the most likely candidate is PubSub. You'll be able to attach a PubSub topic to a secret and then subscribe to that topic.